# sendgrid delivered malware - what's the abuse reporting procedure

Tags: malware, email, phishing

Sendgrid delivered me malware* - where should I report that?

There was no contact info in the headers and the only abuse contact I could find in whois was domain registrar Godaddy.

Last time I dealt with Godaddy they were pretty gung-ho against spam and I really don't want to face sendgrids lawyers because I work for a different, smaller, email delivery company.

I have reported it to the claimed sender's scam channel.

(*) virustotal.com gives 10 positive results for "adwind" malware

Comment: Close votes aren't anonymous, though, and they include a reason.

Comment: Where to report to a specific vendor is not a security question.

Answer (score 1):

### Try and contact the suspect/victim first

It's possible that the entity you got this email from is a victim instead of an offender. It's polite to contact them first and report the issue. If you can't contact them (or they don't reply nor care), you can escalate it to SendGrid, and after that possibly even to GoDaddy.

- For authenticated domain SendGrid provides a [Forwarding abuse](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/mail/#forwarding-abuse) feature:

  > **Forwarding abuse**

> The email address specified in the Forward Spam mail setting may also
> be used to receive emails sent to `abuse@` and `postmaster@` role
> addresses if you have authenticated your domain.
>
> For example, if you create a valid authenticated domain with a custom
> return path of sub and a root domain example and have turned on
> Forward Spam, any emails sent to `abuse@sub.example.com` or
> `postmaster@sub.example.com` will be forwarded to the email address
> you entered in the Forward Spam mail setting.

- If the company is following the [RFC 2142, 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2142#section-4), they could also have an `abuse@example.com` and/or `security@example.com` address available.
- ...or possibly a more "modern" [`/.well-known/security.txt`](https://securitytxt.org/) file in place.

---

**The abuse email information was available on SendGrid's web site.**

1. Go to https://sendgrid.com/
2. Click on [Contact Us](https://sendgrid.com/contact-us-form/)

   > Report abuse

> SendGrid is an email provider, but we don’t send messages directly to
> end-users. Please report email abuse to us, and we will be in touch.
>
> [Report spam](https://sendgrid.com/report-spam/)

3. Click on *Report spam*.

   > If you discover spam that was sent by a SendGrid customer, please

> report it to our team by sending it to **abuse@sendgrid.com**.
>
> Our agents will be able to process your spam sample more quickly if
> you provide us with the **full email headers** of the offending message.

---

**The contact information on WHOIS is behind a [privacy feature](https://uk.godaddy.com/domains/full-domain-privacy-and-protection):**

> Registrant Email: Select Contact Domain Holder link at
> https://www.godaddy.com/whois/results.aspx?domain=SENDGRID.COM

From there I can find another similar abuse email address, but won't paste it here for the same reason. It is their own i.e. not the one specified as `Registrar Abuse Contact Email`.

Comment: I found two different "contact us" on that page, but neither leads to "report" anything.

Comment: Oh, it's under contact sales.... that makes no sense at all - not your fault.

Comment: It's a bit more user friendly on mobile, and also the first non-paid result of Google search `sendgrid abuse report`.